# Is $f(z)=a_0+a_1\frac{1}{z}$ bounded on the right half-plane or on the closed planes $\{z\in\mathbb C:\text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha>0\}\subseteq\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, polynomials, complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:D(f)\subseteq\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be defined by
$$f(z)=a_0+a_1\frac{1}{z},$$
where $a_0,a_1\in\mathbb R$.

**Problem:** Is $f$ bounded on the closed, right half-plane $\{z\in\mathbb C:\text{Re}(z)\ge0\}\subseteq\mathbb C$, or, on closed planes of the form $\{z\in\mathbb C:\text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha>0\}\subseteq\mathbb C$? In the affirmative case, what is the infimum choice of $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ for which $f$ is bounded?

**Attempt:** For $z\in\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge0\}$ we have that $|f(z)|=\left|a_0+a_1\frac1z\right|$, and note that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\left|a_0+a_1\frac1z\right|=\infty$, so that $f$ is not bounded on the half plane.

Let $\text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha>0$ and consider $z\in\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha\}$. Then, $\sup_{\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha\}}|f(z)|=M<\infty$ is attained for $w\in\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha\}$ with $\text{Im}(w)=0$, so that $w$ is closer to zero in absolute value than any other $r\in\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha\}$.

Hence, $f$ is bounded on closed planes of the form $\{z\in\mathbb C: \text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha\}\subset\mathbb C$, when $\alpha>0$. The infimum choice of $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ for which this holds is then $\alpha=0$.

Is this correct? Is my reasoning well founded and water-tight? Or is there anything on which to be improved?

--

*Rephrased question in accord with the more succinct and elegant suggestion of @BrevanEllefsen - my thanks for this.*

Comment: *"for the second case the infimum should be given by $\alpha = 0$"* - what makes you say this? You are right; $\lim_{z \to 0} |a_0 + \frac{a_1}{z}| = \infty$, so we would have to remove a small neighborhood around the origin to get a finite supremum

Comment: This whole question can be summarized as asking "Is $a_0 + \tfrac{a_1}{z}$ ($a_0, a_1 \neq 0$) bounded on the closed, right half-plane $\Re(z) \ge 0$ or only on closed planes $\Re(z) \ge \alpha > 0$?" It turns out the answer is the latter in a fairly general sense, because of Liouville's Theorem - if you replace $z \mapsto 1/z$ in a holomorphic function you should expect unboundedness about the origin unless you start with a constant function (here we are applying this transformation to the linear function $a_0 + a_1 z$)

Comment: Liouville's theorem asserts that if there exists an $M\in\mathbb R$ such that $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$, then $f$ must be constant. Hence, for, $f$ to be non-constant, it follows that there must exist $z\in\mathbb C$ for when $|f(z)|$ is unbounded. So that we need to look outside a neighbourhood about the origin (the radius of which is determined by $\text{Re}(z)\ge\alpha>0$). This means that the infimum choice of radius, although we never actually apply it, is $\alpha=0$?

Comment: Hmm, but Liouville requires $f$ to be entire on all of $\mathbb C$, for which $f(z)=a_0+\frac{a_1}{z}$ is not?

Comment: You misunderstood - we apply Liouville's Theorem to the linear function $a_0 + b_0 z$ and *then* take the transformation $z \mapsto 1/z$. This was not to answer your question - this just shows that the behavior here is general; you should expect some form of blowup about the origin. The answer to your question, as I said in a previous comment, is that you are completely right - unless we remove an open neighborhood about the origin, we can only conclude $f(z) = a_0 + \tfrac{b_0}{z}$ is bounded in *closed* half planes $\Re(z) \ge \alpha > 0 $ since $\lim_{t \to 0} f(it) = \infty$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, this has been incredibly insightful; my thanks for your patience in helping me to understand these aspects related to the problem

Comment: You nead to say $a_1\ne 0.$